# MySQL delete with inner join but foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database. I would like to delete all matches where `places.match_no > 26` and `matches.chart_id = 106`.

```
DELETE matches
FROM kk_matches AS matches
INNER JOIN places ON places.id = matches.place_id
  AND places.match_no > 26
WHERE matches.chart_id = 106
```

This will cause an error:

`#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails...`

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another table in your database which has a foreign key to the kk_matches table. Before you can delete a record in the kk_matches table, you need to delete any records in other tables that point to that record in kk_matches. Otherise you would be "orphaning" those other records.

Foreign Keys exist as a means of avoiding these sort of operations that will cause your data to become irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

> What to do?

Delete the child table dependent row first and then go for deleting parent table row. What you should have actually done is defining `CASCADE` option while defining your `FOREIGN KEY` saying `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Another option is to have a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger and in there do `DELETE` the child table rows

Comment: The child table has `ON DELETE NO ACTION` and that's what I want to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete a row that has a field referenced by a foreign key constraint. You must delete the referencing row first, then delete the row you want (or drop the constraint, if it wasn't intended).

Check this tutorial for more info:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp